# Error occurred while passing your function triggers. Reference Error: Client Id is not defined

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I get a reference error to my client id.

code :

```
const app = dialogflow( {
     clientId : XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX1.apps.googleusercontent.com,
     debug : true,
    });
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hNUB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding quotes around your client ID. The error tells you that a variable is not defined, so most likely it is trying to look for a variable with the same name as your client id because you haven't defined it as a string.

```
clientId : "XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX1.apps.googleusercontent.com",
```